# Main story of Gta5 ps3 missions won't load

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I finished the [Merryweather heist](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Merryweather_Heist) and no more missions are loading I'm not sure what I need to do, I haven't played in awhile help would he greatly appreciated!